How to Measure Test Coverage for a Custom Quarkus Extension?
I have been working on creating a custom Quarkus extension and followed the official Quarkus guide to do so.
Now, I am trying to measure the test coverage of my extension using JaCoCo. I added the JaCoCo dependency to the parent pom.xml, but the coverage report does not include the runtime code of the extension.
Is there a way to measure the test coverage of the actual runtime logic in my Quarkus extension?
resources:
writing your own extenstion
building my first extension
measuring the coverage of your tests
I try to find if there is a way to measure the test coverage of a quarkus-extension
